# Find row-wise minima in sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix, accumarray

I would like to get the minimum nonzero values per row in a sparse matrix. Solutions I found for dense matrices suggested masking out the zero values by setting them to `NaN` or `Inf`. However, this obviously doesn't work for sparse matrices.

Ideally, I should get a column vector of all the row-wise minima, as I would get with

```
minValues = min( A, [], 2);
```

Except, obviously, using `min` leaves me with an all-zeros column vector due to the sparsity. Is there a solution using `find`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is perfect for [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html).  Consider the following sparse matrix,

```
vals = [3 1 1 9 7 4 10 1];  % got this from randi(10,1,8)
S = sparse([1 3 4 4 5 5 7 9],[2 2 3 6 7 8 8 11],vals);
```

Get the minimum value for each row, assuming 0 for empty elements:

```
[ii,jj] = find(S);
rowMinVals = accumarray(ii,nonzeros(S),[],@min)
```

Note that rows 4 and 5 of `rowMinVals`, which are the only two rows of S with multiple nonzero values are equal to the min of the row:

```
rowMinVals =
     3
     0
     1
     1 % min([1 9]
     4 % min([7 4]
     0
    10
     0
     1
```

If the last row(s) of your sparse matrix do not contain any non-zeros, but you want your min row value output to reflect that you have `numRows`, for example, change the`accumarray` command as follows,

```
rowMinVals = accumarray(ii,nonzeros(S),[numRows 1],@min).
```

Also, perhaps you also want to avoid including the default `0` in the output.  One way to handle that is to set the `fillval` input argument to `NaN`:

```
rowMinVals = accumarray(ii,nonzeros(S),[numRows 1],@min,NaN)

rowMinVals =

     3
   NaN
     1
     1
     4
   NaN
    10
   NaN
     1
   NaN
   NaN
   NaN
```

Or you can keep using a sparse matrix with the fifth input argument, `issparse`:

```
>> rowMinVals = accumarray(ii,nonzeros(S),[],@min,[],true)
    rowMinVals =
   (1,1)        3
   (3,1)        1
   (4,1)        1
   (5,1)        4
   (7,1)       10
   (9,1)        1
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the very elaborate answer!

Comment: Go big or go home, right? But seriously, `accumarray` is a very versatile function.  It is also a nice alternate way to make a histogram.